# Problema con un array de objetos

Tags: java, arraylist

He creado una clase de objeto llamado ficha. Luego he creado un metodo para introducir las variables del objeto. Después, otro método para agregar esa "ficha" a un array de fichas.
luego desde el main le doy al usuario la opción de crear una nueva ficha o de ver las existentes (o salir).
El problema es que a pesar de crear varias fichas, cuando quiero ver una de ellas, sin importar cual seleccione, me muestra siempre la última que fue creada. No entiendo porqué pasa eso.

```
'''import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pswd {

  static class Ficha {      //clase de objeto
    String servicio;
    String usuario;
    String contrasena;
  }

  static Ficha nuevaFicha (Ficha myObj) {     //metodo Nueva Ficha

    Scanner myInp = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Ingresa servicio");
    myObj.servicio = myInp.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingresa Usuario");
    myObj.usuario = myInp.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingresa Contrasena");
    myObj.contrasena = myInp.nextLine();

    return myObj;

  }

  static Ficha[] agregarFicha (Ficha[] arrayDeFichas, Ficha myObj, int i) {

    //método: agrega la ficha creada al Array de fichas
    arrayDeFichas[i]=myObj;
    System.out.println(i);
    return arrayDeFichas;
  }

  public static void main (String[] args) {

    int i=0;
    int exit =0;
    Ficha myObj= new Ficha();
    Ficha[] arrayDeFichas = new Ficha[1000];

    System.out.println("¿Desea ver una ficha?(v) o ¿desea agregar una ficha?(a)");


    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String respuesta = scan.nextLine();


    do {
      if (respuesta.equals("a")){

        Ficha mFicha = nuevaFicha(myObj);
        arrayDeFichas = agregarFicha(arrayDeFichas,mFicha,i);
        i++;
        System.out.println("¿Desea ver una ficha?(v) o ¿desea agregar una ficha?(a)");
        respuesta = scan.nextLine();

      } else if (respuesta.equals("v")){

          System.out.println("Ingrese el número de ficha que quiere ver");
          Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
          int j=scan2.nextInt();

          if (arrayDeFichas[j]==null){
            System.out.println("la ficha no existe");
          } else {
            System.out.println("El servicio es: "+ arrayDeFichas[j].servicio);
            System.out.println("El usuario es: "+ arrayDeFichas[j].usuario);
            System.out.println("La contrasena es: "+ arrayDeFichas[j].contrasena);

            System.out.println("¿Desea ver una ficha?(v) o ¿desea agregar una ficha?(a)");
            respuesta = scan.nextLine();
          }

      } else if (respuesta.equals("s")){
        exit=1;
      } else {
        System.out.println("La opción no existe. Escriba (v) o (a)");
        respuesta = scan.nextLine();
      }
    } while(exit==0);

  }
}'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que estás almacanando en cada posición del arreglo el mismo objeto ya que el método `nuevaFicha()` no crea un nuevo objeto en cada llamada, sino que le asgina los datos recibidos por la consola al objeto que le pasas por parámetros, y como este lo creas al inicio del método pues vas a tener en todas las posiciones del arreglo el mismo objeto conteniendo los últimos datos introducidos.

Para corregir esto elimina esta línea: `Ficha myObj= new Ficha();`

y modifca el método `nuevaFicha()` para que el sea el encargado de crear el objeto a devolver, así:

```
static Ficha nuevaFicha () {

    Ficha ficha = new Ficha();

    Scanner myInp = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Ingresa servicio");
    ficha.servicio = myInp.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingresa Usuario");
    ficha.usuario = myInp.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Ingresa Contrasena");
    ficha.contrasena = myInp.nextLine();

    return ficha;

}
```

**Fuera del tema**

El método `agregarFicha()` no necesita devolver el mismo arreglo que modifica puesto que al pasarle la referencia todos los cambios que se hagan sobre esta dentro del método también se verán fera de este método.

Comment: Justo iba a darle clic a "enviar respuesta" y me la ganaste... xD

Comment: @MrDave1999 de todos modos quizás aportes algo diferente a la mía. Saludos